# Trac Account section

Tags: configuration, trac

I have installed Bitnami Trac for windows. (bitnami-trac-windows-installer) and I created new projects but the new project is wrong. I couldn't see Account section in Admin tab also I didn't create an admin but the first admin is assigned to new projects automatically. How to see Account section (configuration , users) ? 
Thanks for your advance .

Comment: Did you login with the user you've setup as admin during the Bitnami installation? That account has TRAC_ADMIN permissions and then you should be able to see the Account section.

Comment: Thanks for returning.Yes I did.I already seen Account section in the first project but I didn't see it in the second one. I don't know why.Maybe it isn't supposed to be in the new projects?

Comment: How did you create new projects? I guess your term 'project' actually means Trac instances, right? Each Trac instance has its own trac.db. Please, explain that in your question as edit.

Comment: While BitNami was installing , an initial project is created .(This requires a directory for Trac(MyTrac) and a project name Project1) Firstly , I created new project by this way ; I specify MyTrac as a project directory (trac-admin path (C:\MyTrac\NewProject) initenv) .New project is created in MyTrac folder but it didn't work and then I have searched for it and it need to be in MyTrac\Project1 (trac-admin path (C:\MyTrac\Project1\NewProject )initenv ) . My problem is I can't see Account section in NewProject .

Comment: Can't you see the Account section with MyTrac\NewProject or MyTrac\Project1\NewProject ?

Comment: I can't see The Account section in MyTrac\Project1\NewProject

Comment: Did you change MyTrac\NewProject to MyTrac\Project1\NewProject somehow, or did you reinstall Bitnami Trac, or how did you get to the second project?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`trac-admin` command-line tool](http://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/TracAdmin) to adjust account permissions.  When setting up a project, I typically give `TRAC_ADMIN` permissions to the anonymous user with something like:

```
trac-admin path\to\trac\project permission add anonymous TRAC_ADMIN
```

This should give you full access to everything, even without logging in.  Once you get the admin accounts set up and can verify they're working and have the correct permissions, you can revoke that permission with `permission remove`.

Since it sounds like you already have the admin accounts created, this might be overkill.  It may be enough to just add the `TRAC_ADMIN` permission to your specific admin account.  To verify that the permissions are set up as expected, you can use:

```
trac-admin path\to\trac\project permission list username
```